# Set RWX for files too (only set for folders) ACL

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

Using the following set of permissions, default RWX is set for user.
For some reasons this won't affect new created files.

Any idea how to get RWX permissions for new created files (under /home/admin) too?

```
root@admin:# getfacl /home/admin/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/admin/
# owner: admin
# group: some_group
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```

**As "admin" user**

```
admin@admin:~$ mkdir test1
admin@admin:~$ getfacl test1
# file: test1
# owner: admin
# group: some_group
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---

admin@admin:~$ touch test1/testfile
admin@admin:~$ getfacl test1/testfile
# file: test1/testfile
# owner: admin
# group: some_group
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---
```

As you can see, no RWX permissions set for the created file.

Are ACLs required or is there any chance of achieving the same result using `umask`?

Comment: Did you set the `-d` option during `setfacl` so that future files/dirs will inherit this as the default in future?

Comment: Yes for sure, as you can see, the directory is created with correct permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK by default there is no way to add `x` flag to files when created. Because this is special flag (able to exec the file) it must be set by hand postfactum